# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /vendor/symfony/string/Resources/functions.php on line 34 lot of problem faced from the vendor

Tags: php, laravel

php version 8.1.10 and composer 2.4.4 still face this problem
This problem is faced when i upload the laravel project into the
cpanel mostly problem shown from the vendor folder like syntax error.

> 1:33 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /vendor/symfony/string/Resources/functions.php on line 34

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "platform-check": false,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this message on the command line or on a webpage? Double-check that the php version is what you think. `php -v` if the error is on the command line, or create a file with `<?php phpinfo();` in your public directory, and view that in the browser.

Comment: there is auto-generate error_log file in the public_html directory. I have found those errors in that error_log file

Comment: Then it's a web error, so create that file with `phpinfo()` to find out what version your web PHP actually is

Comment: Oh, from the cpanel i have simple change the php version 7 to 8 and it work now!

Comment: thank you for your kindly attention for my questions. it need a simple task, it is just happend for you attention and remind me to check version like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the php version in cpanel are set to php 7. So check that in php info and then change it from multiphp manager, then it should work